# how can I add a django array element into a js array using an if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, chart.js

I have a Django project with data being submitted by form , I am trying to use chart.js to display the data. I need to check whether an array exists() if so then add an item to  'labels' array in 'mycharts.js' . Heres what I have so far

django views.py

```
    ing1 = request.POST.getlist('ingredients1')
    ing2 = request.POST.getlist('ingredients2')
    ing3 = request.POST.getlist('ingredients3')
```

( I've passed the above into my context )

mycharts.js

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {chart.js
        labels: ['{{ing1.0}}', '{{ing2.0}}', {% if ing3|length > 1 %} '{{ing3.0}}', {% endif %}],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
(etc...)
```

if I take out the if statement inside of 'labels' array , then it shows the 'ing1' and 'ing2' headings , but I can't get it to work with this if statement , whats the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Can you surround your `if` with quotes ? See if that works .

Answer (score 0):

I put 'ing1, 'ing2' and 'ing3' into a list called 'title' inside my views , then put that list into the context , then did the following inside the chart.js script :

```
{% for item in title %} '{{ item }}', {% endfor %}
```

now it adds the correct data to the labels array.